# Matrix Multiplication using two classes

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

So in my Computer Science class we are going over Matrix Multiplication and I got a little stuck. We are to multiply to matrices that are varying in dimensions. Here is the first class and I need help figuring out how to print my results after the for-loops are complete.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{1, 2, -2, 0}, {-3, 4, 7, 2}, {6, 0, 3, 1}};
        int[][] b = {{-1, 3}, {0, 9}, {1, -11}, {4, -5}};
        int[][] c = MatrixMult.mult(a, b);

        for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < b[0].length; r++) {
                //where the results are printed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this is the other class which has the Matrix Multiplication function in it. I couldn't figure out what to put after the `sum+=` to finish the loops and return ans.

```java
public class MatrixMult {
    public static int[][] mult(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
        int cRows = a.length;
        int cCols = b[0].length;
        int[][] ans = new int[cRows][cCols];

        for (int r = 0; i < cRows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; j < cCols; c++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int r1 = 0; int r1 < a[0].length; r1++) {
                    sum += // I'm not sure what I put here
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

The output after all is finished should be:

```
-3 43
18 -60
1 -20
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a hint.

When multiplying matrices **`A * B = C`**, you are iterating rows of **`A`** (variable `i`) and columns of **`B`** (variable `j`). `C[i][j]` is equal to:

```
(A[i][0] * B[0][j]) + (A[i][1] * B[1][j]) + (A[i][2] * B[2][j]) + ...
```

You add the values in brackets to your sum, and then assign it to `C[i][j]`.

Try to figure it out by examining this pattern.